# scala dataframe column names replace '-' with _ for nested json

Tags: json, scala, apache-spark, nested

I am working with Nested json, using scala and need to replace the `-` in column names with `_`.

Schema of json:

```
 |-- a-type: struct (nullable = true)
 |    |-- x-Type: array (nullable = true)
 |    |    |-- element: string (containsNull = true)
 |    |-- part: array (nullable = true)
 |    |    |-- element: struct (containsNull = true)
 |    |    |    |-- x-Type: array (nullable = true)
 |    |    |    |    |-- element: string (containsNull = true)
 |    |    |    |-- Length: long (nullable = true)
 |    |    |    |-- Order: long (nullable = true)
 |    |    |    |-- y-Name: string (nullable = true)
 |    |    |    |-- Payload-Text: string (nullable = true)
 |    |-- Date: string (nullable = true)
```

I am using below code which only works at first level. However, I have to replace `-` with `_` at all levels. Any help is really appreciated.

Code used currently:

```
scJsonDF.columns.foreach { col =>
    println(col + " after column replace " + col.replaceAll("-", ""))
    scJsonDFCorrectedCols = scJsonDFCorrectedCols.withColumnRenamed(col, col.replaceAll("-", "")
    )
}
```

I am looking for a dynamic solution as there are different structures available.

Comment: basically, if you want to do something recursively with your spark dataframe, you can just forget spark sql methods since it doesn't support recursive feature. The solution i think of is to define a UDF if luckily your schema is not dynamic.

Answer (score 0):

One of the solution I found is to flatten the json and update column names. I used link here to help https://gist.github.com/fahadsiddiqui/d5cff15698f9dc57e2dd7d7052c6cc43 and updated a line

```
  col(x.toString).as(x.toString.replace(".", "_"))


  col(x.toString).as(x.toString.replaceAll("-","_").replace(".", "_"))
```